# Unexplained mv permission denied for directory with ACL

Tags: permissions, acl

I have a folder A inside a folder B, which is in turn in a folder C (all on the same file system). I want to mv A from B to C, but I get a permission denied error.

I can mv A within B (i.e. rename A)

Now I mv A to C as the root user (successfully)

I can now mv/rename A within C

```
└── [drwxrwx---]  C
    ├── [drwxrwx---]  B
    │   └── [drwxr-x---]  A

getfacl C
# file: C
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:myuser:rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::---

getfacl B
# file: B
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:myuser:rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::---

getfacl A
# file: A
# owner: otheruser
# group: othergroup
user::rwx
user:myuser        #effective:r-x
group::rwx         #effective:r-x
mask::r-x
other::---

mv A ..
mv: cannot move ‘A’ to ‘C’: Permission denied
```

This doesn't make sense to me, since I understood moving a directory only requires write permissions on the current parent and the target directory. Since I can rename the dir in both directories, surely I should be able to mv it from one to the other!

Additional notes:

1. The permission is granted via an ACL named user entry (myuser), that exists on both B and C and which has rwx permissions
2. These folders are contained within a Samba share - but even if I stop the smb service I still have the same problem, so I don't think that has any impact.
3. SELinux is in Permissive mode
4. There is no existing folder in C also named A
5. If I do sudo chmod g+w A, then I can move A successfully. But why does the permissions on the folder being moved have an impact?
6. OS is CentOS 7, and the file system is ext4. The file system was not mounted explicitly with acl support (but acls seem to work nonetheless - except for this one issue). tune2fs -l shows "Default mount options: user_xattr acl"

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add an actual example, with the commands, and the permissions of the files and directories you are using so we can understand exactly what you mean. You can just show us the output of `tree -p`.

Comment: @terdon - have edited question with details

Comment: Thanks. So what commands are you running? You say you move things around, please show us the actual commands so we can test and understand exactly what you've done.  What you describe seems normal to me, so I don't understand what you were expecting. Is the confusion that you think the file's permissions are what controls renaming? It's actually the directory's permissions (if you have write access to A, you can freely rename things in A), is that what you are asking about?

Comment: @terdon - have added the mv command I am using. I don't think the permissions of the file/folder being moved should affect the ability to move it. Only the parent dir and the target dir. That is why I am confused

Comment: "I understood moving a directory only requires rx permissions on the current parent and the target directory" ... You'd of course need write permissions on both directories to be able to modify directory entries in them (which includes adding, removing or renaming directories)

Comment: But your user doesn't have write or execute access to `B/` so why are you expecting to have the right to delete things from it?

Comment: @terdon - I meant to say "moving a directory only requires write permissions on the current parent and the target directory" - have edited question. I am doing the mv as myuser who has write and execute access to B (via the ACL)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant `mv A C` is a shorthand of something like `mv A ..` (relative destination path) or `mv A /some/path.../C` (absolute destination path).

If so, is there another instance of A in C, which is not writeable by you? That would explain the "permission denied" error: if you cannot write into existing `.../C/A`, you cannot move the contents of `.../C/B/A` into it, causing the `mv` operation to fail.

But if your command was `mv A C` **with no paths specified**, then the command would be trying to rename `.../C/B/A` into `.../C/B/C`, not move it to `.../C/A`. And again, if there is an existing `.../C/B/C` which is not writeable by you, it would cause the `mv` operation to fail with a `permission denied` error message.

Comment: Yes the command is mv A .. and there is no existing file in C named 'A' (have corrected the question).

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mv_(Unix)

Moving a directory from one parent to a different parent directory requires write permission in the directory being moved, in addition to permissions to modify the old and new parents. This is because the i-number for the directory entry ".." (which can be used in any context as an alias for the parent of the current directory) changes as a result of the rename.